# How do you make the graph relative in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a simple graph in Google Spreadsheet just showing weights from different dates. The problem I have is that the graph is starting from 0, giving it a lot of dead space. I want it to be relative to the weights available.

In the thumbnail (before editing a spreadsheet), the graph is correct, but inside the document it's wrong.

Wrong:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

How can I make the graph relative insetead of starting from 0?

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative ranging is simply not a feature Sheets charts. (At least not with the new Material theme and GUI?). If this is a real problem for you, you may choose Report a Problem from the Sheets Help menu—Google says they welcome feedback.

Oherwise,  Chart editor → Customize → Vertical axis → Min: 62 , Max: 63.8

Or perhaps base the chart on a new column with each of column B's values' difference from the minimum. E.g. in C2 enter:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B),B2:B-MIN(B$2:B),""))`